# VS Code - Snippet Transform text with spaces for test methods

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I've had this useful snippet in **Sublime Text 3** for a while, and I am trying to replicate it in **VS Code** but with no success.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/** @test */
public function ${1/\s/_/g}()
{
    ${0:// ${1:type name of method with spaces}}
}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>phpunit</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.php</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

I've basically created the same snippet in **VS Code** but it complains that `\s` is an invalid escape character.

[image: Picture showing snippet error in VS Code]

Where am I going wrong? Is it missing support for finding space characters?

Would like to get this snippet working again as it's a useful time saver.

Comment: Try double escaping that, or even three escapes.  I can't check right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just double-escape it:

```
public function ${1/\\s/_/g}()
```

and it'll work fine.  See [transform examples and escaping](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_transform-examples):

> The examples are shown within double quotes, as they would appear inside a snippet body, to illustrate the need to double escape certain characters.

Comment: Thanks - but afraid double escaping has no effect.

Comment: I see I had made a typo previously - I just fixed it above and I had previously tested it.  It works.

Comment: Ah right - you **must** press "tab" again after typing for the transform to take affect. On Sublime, you see it transform as you type. Confirm that double escaping (your example above) works :)